# Changing values of a numpy array using another array as a reference without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have this array

```
x = np.array([0,0,0
              1,1,1
              2,2,2])
```

and

```
y = np.array([4,5,6])
```

I'd like `x` to become

```
[4,4,4
 5,5,5
 6,6,6]
```

meaning,  `i` in x becomes `y[i]`. I have a feeling fancy indexing will be my help, but I'm new to numpy and struggling.

input;

```
[[  0   0   0 ... 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 ... 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 ... 255 255 255]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ... 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 ... 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 ... 255 255 255]]
```

and my desired output, given `y` of length 256, `y = np.array([5,6,7.......261])`

```
[[  5    ... 261]
 [  5    ... 261]
 [  5    ... 261]
 ...
 [  5    ... 261]
 [  5    ... 261]
 [  5    ... 261]]
```

Comment: Please provide a small working example (input and expected output)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Done, I think this covers everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have (which I think you want):

```
x = np.array([[0,0,0],
              [1,1,1],
              [2,2,2]])

y = np.array([4,5,6])
```

then:

```
y[x]

Out: 
array([[4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6]])
```

That's . . . just how indexing works :)

Comment: Wow do I feel dumb. this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.repeat`:

```
>>> np.repeat(y, x.size / y.size)
array([4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will this works for 2D arrays as well?

Comment: @Omri.B Please update your question with the desired details and I'll work on it

Comment: Edited. Tried to simplify it but went too far.